# SecurityContextHolder returns correctly login user as "anonymous" in junit tests

Tags: spring

I have tried two methods to make a controller unit test.

M1:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class WorkOrderControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails(value="Tom", userDetailsServiceBeanName = "customizedUserDetailsService")
    public void testGetworkList() {
        URI uri = URI.create("/foo");
        ResponseEntity exchange = testRestTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class);
    }
}
```

M2:

```
@Test
public void testGetworkList() throws Exception {

    List<GrantedAuthority> list = ...;
    String uri = "/foo";

    ResultActions perform = mvc.perform(post(uri).with(csrf().asHeader()).with(user("Tom").roles("CP").authorities(list)));
}

@Before
public void setup() {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
        .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()) 
        .build();
}
```

They both perform correctly login (spring security would block any request otherwise) and thereafter enters controller method. For M1, statements behind controller: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`, which should contain correct `SecurityUser`, returns "anonymous". And for M2: a spring User pojo is returned. Because I have to use `customizedUserDetailsService` bean for its generated customized user pojo. Is this a **Spring bug**? I found more:  in M1, SecurityContextHolder setContext is called twice, the 1st context argument is correct, contained my own user pojo while the 2nd context argument is wrong, and I believe this is the reason resulting "anonymous".

**SOLUTION**

A guy on GH commented on M1 that I mixed up integration test and mock test, and `@WithUserDetails` is for mock tests. So I used `@WithUserDetails` and `MockMvc` (a combination of M1 and M2), and the results show that it achieves my goals:

1. a user login, passed through customizedUserDetailsService bean.
2. SecurityContextHolder returns the login user.

code:

```
@Test
@WithUserDetails(value="Tom", userDetailsServiceBeanName = "customizedUserDetailsService")
public void testGetworkList() {
    String uri = ...;
    ResultActions result = mvc.perform(post(uri).with(csrf()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, It's not a bug; That's correct the `SecurityContextHolder` is a **singleton** bean but in a **JUnit** test it is *thread-scoped* not *session-scoped*. and with JUnit you need to set something before.

There are some ways for that, You may use Mokito and set a `SecurityContext` object for the `SecurityContextHolder`:

```
Authentication authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
SecurityContext securityContext = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);
Mockito.when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
//Now you can access the real user loggedin
```

Comment: `@WithUserDetails(value="Tom", userDetailsServiceBeanName = "customizedUserDetailsService")` should not return an anonymous user. The second method mockXXX does not past through customizedUserDetailsService bean, which returns a needed pojo.

Comment: Then you don't have to use `@WithUserDetails`, you may set it though `mvc.perform(post(uri)....`

Comment: mvc.with method induces a Spring User, not a customized user bean. I need that bean.

Comment: `SecurityContextHolder setContext` method runs 2 times, the first time argument context is correct, the 2 time argument context results in the final "anonymous". I still believe **this is a bug**, should not happen with `@WithUserDetails`

Comment: I'll check it completely when having time; The solution and codes I posted was from my previous experience, I hope it was useful, and sorry for not being helpful more